# View modifications are dismissed in Xcode, after unwinding

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The setup of my storyboard in Xcode is very simple:

I have two views, controlled by two view controllers: firstViewController and secondViewController.

The first view has just one button, called "NEXT", which segues to the second view. The second view has two buttons, called "BLACK" and "RETURN". Pressing RETURN successfully unwinds the segue to the first view, and pressing BLACK changes the background colour of the second view to black. Both views have blue backgrounds when the app starts.

I press BLACK, the second view changes colour as expected. But after I unwind and press NEXT again, the second view has the blue background, not the black one.

I searched the web and found something about a stack that Xcode uses to manage its views. When unwinding, the stack "goes down a level", so it is intuitive that the second view "gets destroyed", along with the new black colour. But even if I don't unwind, and simply use another segue (the stack goes up a level) the changes will still be dismissed. It seems that Xcode keeps the original settings of both views when segueing back and forth.

**How do we stop the changes to the views being dismissed when segueing back and forth?** (in particular the background colour)

Comment: What do you mean by "But even if I don't unwind, and simply use another segue (the stack goes up a level) the changes will still be dismissed." Do you mean presenting a third view from the second view?

Comment: No, there is no third view. Instead of unwinding, I can create another segue from the second view to the first view. So we are going to have two segues: one from the first to the second, and another from the second to the first. But from what I've searched the internet, this form of "segueing" would cause the stack to grow too large eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of `UINavigationController`.

1. You are on `firstViewController`, only it is on stack.

   > Stack: `firstViewController`.
2. You tap next, `secondViewController` is allocated and inited and added to the stack.

   > Stack: `firstViewController`, `secondViewController`.
3. You tap back, the `UINavigationConnectroller` deallocates memory used by that `secondViewController` and removes it from the stack.

   > Stack: `firstViewController`.
4. You once again tap next, new `secondViewController` is allocated and inited and added to the stack.

   > Stack: `firstViewController`, `secondViewController`.

The object from step 2 and step 4 are totally different objects. Your approach is wrong, because keeping it in the memory is not efficient. You just need the information if the background was saved.

So instead of your solution, when you press 'back' you should save that the color was changed, and then overload `SecondViewController init` method, read the parameter if it was changed and set the background accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the second view controller with the black background was removed from the stack and recreated when you press the next button on the first view controller again.